# AlertController not working when called in FCMPlugin Ionic 2

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic2, cordova-plugins

Tried to create an alert with AlertController in an ionic app inside the FCMPlugin.onNotification(), but the alert controller does not get created. In fact the method appears to stop and no more console.log() work after the alert is created in code.

```
  pushNoteSetup(){
if(typeof(FCMPlugin) !== "undefined"){
  FCMPlugin.getToken(function(t){
    console.log("Use this token for sending device specific messages\nToken: " + t);

  }, function(e){
    console.log("Uh-Oh!\n"+e);
  });

  this.confirmAlert('Hi');

  FCMPlugin.onNotification(
    function(d){
      if(d.wasTapped){
        // Background receival (Even if app is closed),
        //   bring up the message in UI
        let message = d['aps']['alert'];
        console.log('Message received: ' + message);
         this.alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
          title: 'Hi',
          message: 'Boo',
          buttons: ['Ok']
        });
        this.alert.present();
        console.log('Should have displayed an alert');
        this.confirmAlert(message);
        console.log('Skipping over alers?');
      } else {
        let message = d['aps']['alert'];
        console.log('Message received: ' + message);
        let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
          title: 'Hi',
          message: 'Boo',
          buttons: ['Ok']
        });
        alert.present();
        console.log('Should have displayed an alert');
        this.confirmAlert(message);
        console.log('Skipping over alers?');
        this.confirmAlert(message);
      }
    }, function(msg){
      // No problemo, registered callback
      console.log('Message:' + msg);
    }, function(err){
      console.log("Arf, no good mate... " + err);
    });
  } else {

    console.log("Notifications disabled, only provided in Android/iOS environment");
  }
}
public confirmAlert(message: any){
let mesg = String(message);

console.log('Message to display '  + mesg + ' and ' + message);

let confirmAlert = this.alertCtrl.create({
       title: 'Alert',
       message: message,
       buttons: [{
         text: 'Cancel',
         role: 'cancel',
         handler: () => {
           console.log('cancel');
         }
       }, {
         text: 'Confirm',
         handler: () => {
           console.log('Confirm');
         }
       }]
     });
     confirmAlert.present();

}
```

This is being called after platform.ready() in app.componenet.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using javascript `function` which changes the value of `this`. It will point to the function context. You could try to save the context as:

```
self = this;
```

and withing callback,

```
   function(d){
      if(d.wasTapped){
        // Background receival (Even if app is closed),
        //   bring up the message in UI
        let message = d['aps']['alert'];
        console.log('Message received: ' + message);
         self.alert = self.alertCtrl.create({
          title: 'Hi',
          message: 'Boo',
          buttons: ['Ok']
        });
        self.alert.present();
        //...
```

Or a better way is to use [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

```
FCMPlugin.onNotification(
   (d)=>{
   //create alert
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using javascript as suraj said.

Try using this code instead:

```
if(typeof(FCMPlugin) !== "undefined"){ 


FCMPlugin.getToken(
                 (token)=>{
                    console.log(token);
                },
                 (err)=>{
                    console.log('error retrieving token: ' + err);
                }
            );  



    FCMPlugin.onNotification(
         (data)=>{
            if(data.wasTapped){
                //Notification was received on device tray and tapped by the user.
                //Do something
            }else{
                //Notification was received in foreground. Maybe the user needs to be notified.
              this.alertBox = this.alertCtrl.create({
              title: data.title,
              subTitle: data.body,
              buttons: [{
                text: 'Cancel',
                role: 'cancel',
                handler: () => {
                console.log('cancel');
                }
              }, {
                  text: 'Confirm',
                  handler: () => {
                  console.log('Confirm');
                  }
                 }]
              });     
              this.alertBox.present();                  
            }
        },
         (msg)=>{
            console.log('onNotification callback successfully registered: ' + msg);
        },
         (err)=>{
            console.log('Error registering onNotification callback: ' + err);
        }
    );
 } 
else console.log("Notifications disabled, only provided in Android/iOS environment");
```